# Aptana complaining about JavaScript semicolons

Tags: javascript, validation, aptana

Why does Aptana with either validator (Mozilla or JSlint) complain about this code:

```
var collectionOfValues = {
    key0 : value0;
    key1 : value1;
    key2 : value2;
};
```

It works fine with `,` but not with `;`.

Even code from The Good Parts won't validate:

```
var myObject = {
    value: 0;
    increment: function (inc) {
        this.value += typeof inc === 'number' ? inc : 1;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 8):

It's complaining because that's a syntax error. In an object literal, you separate terms with commas, not semicolons.

```
var collectionOfValues = {
    key0 : value0,
    key1 : value1,
    key2 : value2
};
```

Both your examples would be rejected by every JavaScript implementation I know of.

```
var myObject = {
    value: 0,
    increment: function (inc) {
        this.value += typeof inc === 'number' ? inc : 1;
    }
};
```

This has been the case essentially since the Big Bang.

Comment: Great, thank you for the confirmation.  Just very strange that the code within JavaScript - The Good Parts is wrong, and the documentation for a new API that mentions using JSLint for validation is also wrong, in the same way.  It seemed like if they were both saying ; were ok then maybe they really were ok.

Answer (score 2):

because proper syntax would be

```
var collectionOfValues = {
    key0 : value0,
    key1 : value1,
    key2 : value2,
};
```

for a js object

Comment: the , after value2 is not valid

Comment: sue it is :P it'll run.  It's not a good practice, but it'll run.  I purposefully left it in there as a juxtaposed to the original, highlighting the one thing that when changed made a difference.

Comment: @Joseph actually IE6 won't be able to run that http://www.enterprisedojo.com/2010/12/19/beware-the-trailing-comma-of-death/

Comment: lol thanks for the link, Greg. XD  I didn't know (but probably should have guessed) that IE would have an issue with it.

Comment: Thanks for the information.  I know in C# that arrays can have the trailing comma, and I never knew why, until I started having to modify arrays in code a lot, and that trailing comma sure comes in handy, since you can just add it, and then modify line-by-line and not worry about which line is last, since they all have commas.  In any case, I wish to code JavaScript the 'right way', so thanks.  I wonder if JSLint catches this trailing comma?  I would assume so.  Actually it doesn't... Hmm.  Guess it's ok.

Answer (score 0):

I know that this is a late answer, but The Good Parts is right actually. (The questioner probably knows this, but for anyone else reading this....); my copy is dated 2008 and this post is 2011. It is printed with a comma.

It's the next bit that baffles me... ;-)